# Malihu custom scrollbar lagging?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I tried using this custom scrollbar http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

It lags..when I scroll its takes more than 2 to 3 seconds to scroll...Is there anyone who can help with a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a sample of problematic code. Also, does in happen in different browsers?

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed... :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I had the css3 transition duration added to my div tag, which is causing the problem. I removed the below tags and it worked...

```
    -transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
```